# MEAN STACK : How to remove # from URL

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I have an angular project which is running on expressJS routes:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/build')));
```

example of URL => `localhost:3000/#/login`.

It works fine when navigating between routes via/through the app with or without `#`, however, when I remove the `#` and then hard refresh the page, it doesn't work returning `404`

So my question is, what's the story with `#` and how do I get rid of this behavior?

Angular routes settings:

```
 { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: environment.production ? HashLocationStrategy : PathLocationStrategy },
```

If I remove `HashLocationStrategy` it will not work when hard refreshing the page.

Comment: replace this with providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],

Comment: also in your import remove imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // remove second argument
]

Comment: @HrishikeshKale This is what I have already done with condition production or local. And I have removed `useHash:true`

Comment: have you removed useHash:true from your import?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale, its already removed